# How to improve the Matlab code for faster processing time?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop

I developed some code for my masters project that will simulate 90 years daily data using 1000 different data sets. The code is working fine and gives the correct output that i wanted but the processing time are very high. It took about 8 hours to finish the simulation. Here is the code that i used:

```
    tic
%% importing the csv file with selected column
files=dir('*_scen_*.csv');
for i=1:length(files);
    LHR=importcsv(files(i).name);

%% Definable variables
% Define These Value
TAW=-216;     %total available water
RAW=-129;     %readily available water
KC=1.0;       %crop coefficient
IRL=15;       %intense rain level
RC=(80/100);  %percentage of recharge 
RO=(1-RC);    %percentage of runoff

% The very first row of Soil Moisture Deficit
for j=1
    SMD(j,i)=(LHR.RAIN(j)-LHR.PET(j));
 if     SMD(j,i)>0;
        SMD(j,i)=0;
 elseif SMD(j,i)<RAW;
        SMD(j,i)=(LHR.RAIN(j)-(LHR.PET(j)*((TAW-SMD(j-1))/(TAW-RAW))));
 end
end

%for the following SMD Calculation
for k=2:(length(LHR.RAIN));
    SMD(k,i)=SMD(k-1,i)+(LHR.RAIN(k)-LHR.PET(k));
    % The SMD conditions
    if SMD(k,i)>0;
       SMD(k,i)=0;
 elseif SMD(k,i)<RAW;
     SMD(k,i)=SMD(k-1,i)+(LHR.RAIN(k)-(LHR.PET(k)*((TAW-SMD(k-1,i))/(TAW-RAW))));
    end
end
%Convert negative SMD to Positive
SMD=abs(SMD);

 %%Evapotranspiration Calculation
 for l=1:(length(SMD));
    if SMD(l,i)<abs(RAW);
        AET(l,i)=LHR.PET(l);
    elseif SMD(l,i)>abs(RAW);
        AET(l,i)=KC*LHR.PET(l)*((abs(TAW)-(SMD(l,i)))/(abs(TAW)-abs(RAW)));
    end
end
for m=2:(length(SMD));
    if SMD(m,i)<abs(RAW);
        AET(m,i)=LHR.PET(m);
    elseif SMD(m,i)>abs(RAW);
       AET(m,i)=KC*LHR.PET(m)*((abs(TAW)-(SMD(m-1,i)))/(abs(TAW)-abs(RAW)));
    end
end
%% HER calculation
for n=1:length(SMD);
    if SMD(n,i)<(LHR.RAIN(n)-AET(n,i));
        HER(n,i)=(LHR.RAIN(n)-AET(n,i)-SMD(n,i));
    elseif SMD(n,i)>(LHR.RAIN(n)-AET(n,i));
        HER(n,i)=0;
    end
end
%% Calculation of recharge anf runoff
for o=1:(length(HER));
    if (HER(o,i)+(abs(TAW)-SMD(o,i)))<abs(TAW);
        RUNOFF(o,i)=0;
    elseif (HER(o,i)+(abs(TAW)-SMD(o,i)))>abs(TAW);
        if HER(o,i)>IRL;
            RUNOFF(o,i)=RO*HER(o,i);
        elseif HER(o,i)<IRL;
            RUNOFF(o,i)=0;    
        end
    end
    if (HER(o,i)+(abs(TAW)-SMD(o,i)))<abs(TAW);
        RECHARGE(o,i)=0;
    elseif (HER(o,i)+(abs(TAW)-SMD(o,i)))>abs(TAW);
        if HER(o,i)>IRL;
            RECHARGE(o,i)=RC*HER(o,i);
        elseif HER(o,i)<IRL;
            RECHARGE(o,i)=HER(o,i);
        end
    end
end
%% rainfall
for p=1:length(LHR.RAIN);
RAINFALL(p,i)=LHR.RAIN(p);
PET(p,i)=LHR.PET(p);
end

end
clear i
clear j
clear k
clear l
clear m
clear n
clear o
clear p

toc
```

Is there any improvement scope for this code that might reduce the processing time? Sorry if the code looks unprofessional because i am in the beginner stage for MATLAB programming.

Comment: do you have the Parallel Processing Toolbox?

Comment: Use the matlab profiler to see the bottlenecks. You can do this using the following command sequence: profile on, run_code, profiler viewer.

Comment: Sorry im new to matlab, im not sure i have it or not. How do i can check whether i have parallel processing toolbox?

Comment: I second the use of the matlab profiler. It's a very powerful tool. Also, if you haven't preallocated your arrays, that would help immensely.

Comment: Start with properly formatting your code.

Comment: Is this more on-topic for Code Review? (http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: One of possibly many things you can do with the code is to preallocate large arrays. Before you start your loops add `SMD=zeros(n1,n2)`, where `n1` and `n2` is the desired size in each dimension. If you do not do that Matlab spends enormous amount of time moving the data in `SMD` around whenever you decide `SMD` should have one more row or column (this is what your loops do).

Answer (score 1):

If there is one thing Matlab is good at, it's matrix and vector computations. With your loop-like code, especially for big datasets, you are completely missing this advantage.

I didn't look into the details, but it seems like all your loops do element-wise computations and logical operations. You could replace these by matrix calculations.

For example, let's consider your first loop:

```
for k=2:(length(LHR.RAIN));
    SMD(k,i)=SMD(k-1,i)+(LHR.RAIN(k)-LHR.PET(k));
  % …
end
```

Could be replaced by something like (untested) `SMD(2:end,i)=SMD(1:end-1,i)+LHR.RAIN(1:end-1)-LHR.PET(1:end-1)`

And logical operations like this:

```
for k=2:(length(LHR.RAIN));
    % ...
    % The SMD conditions
    if SMD(k,i)>0;
       SMD(k,i)=0;
    % ...
end
```

Can be replaced by this:

```
SMD(SMD>0)=0;
```

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that speed up (a lot!) scripts is to declare your matrices prior to entering a loop. For example, for your SMD, AET, RECHARGE, etc matrix, you should use something like

```
SMD=NaN(nrow,ncol);
```

where `nrow` and `ncol` is the size of the final matrix (if known of course).

Then do your loop.